# How to reuse DataTemplate definition for two classes that have inheritance relationship between them?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two VMs, one inherit from another

```
public class BasicVM
{

  public SectionTitle SectionTitle{get;set;}
   //snip the common properties...
}

public class InheritedVM:BasicVM
{
   //additional properties and methods
}
```

In UI:

```
public interface ILayoutUpdater
{
}

public class DefaultLayoutUpdater:ILayoutUpdater 
{
}

public class InheritLayoutUpdater:ILayoutUpdater 
{
}
```

The view control also has a dependency property of the type ILayoutUpdater, ie:

```
public class OutputView
{
    public ILayoutUpdater LayoutUpdater
        {
            get { return (ILayoutUpdater)GetValue(LayoutUpdaterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LayoutUpdaterProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutUpdaterProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LayoutUpdater), typeof(ILayoutUpdater), typeof(OutputView)
                , new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLayoutUpdaterChanged)));

 public SectionTitle SectionTitle
        {
            get { return (SectionTitle)GetValue(SectionTitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SectionTitleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SectionTitleProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SectionTitle), typeof(SectionTitle),
                typeof(OutputView), new PropertyMetadata(SectionTitle.Normal, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSectionTitleChanged)));
}
```

The important point is that for `BasicVM` 's View `LayoutUpdater`, it must be assigned `DefaultLayoutUpdater` object whereas for `InheritVM` view `LayoutUpdater`, it must be assigned `InheritLayoutUpdater`.

Now I get the job done in XAML by defining two DataType's DataTemplate as per below.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:BasicVM}">
        <views:OutputView 
            SectionTitle="{Binding SectionTitle}"  
            <!-- snipped 10++ properties -->         
            <views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
                <views:DefaultLayoutUpdater />
            </views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
    </DataTemplate>

 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:InheritedVM}">
        <views:OutputView 
            SectionTitle="{Binding SectionTitle}"  
            <!-- snipped 10++ properties -->         
            <views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
                <views:InheritLayoutUpdater />
            </views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This gets the job done, but there are a lot of duplication, especially those properties that are common in both classes. As you can see, everything is the same except the assignment of `LayoutUpdater`.

How to make the above code so that the duplication is minimized?

Comment: create common style for OutputView  with snipped 10++ properties (setters). apply Style in each template, set LayoutUpdater individually. It is not clear to me why there is LayoutUpdater property in the ViewModel, and in the View

Comment: @ASh, I edit the question, hopefully it's clearer

Comment: did you try common style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create common Style for OutputView and assign it in each template

```
<Style x:Key="CommonOutputView" TargetType="{x:Type views:OutputView}">
     <Setter Property="CommonProperty" Value="CommonValue"/>
</Style>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:BasicVM}">
    <views:OutputView 
        SectionTitle="{Binding SectionTitle}" 
        Style="{StaticResource CommonOutputView}"/>
        <views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
            <views:DefaultLayoutUpdater />
        </views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:InheritedVM}">
    <views:OutputView 
        SectionTitle="{Binding SectionTitle}" 
        Style="{StaticResource CommonOutputView}"/>        
        <views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
            <views:InheritLayoutUpdater />
        </views:OutputView.LayoutUpdater>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: `Style="{StaticResource CommonOutputView}"` also applicable for user defined dependency properties?

Comment: StaticResource is applicable for any property. Style Setter can be used for any DependencyProperty, including attached